# Decomposing $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ ($G$ finite) into products of matrix rings over fields

Tags: finite-fields, group-rings, division-algebras, artinian, semi-simple-rings

I have recently begun learning about group algebras over finite fields but am still a little uncertain about these guys. So I was looking for some clarification and verification. Consider the Wedderburn decompositions for a group ring $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ where $p$ prime and $G$ finite. Then we have three cases:

1) $p\nmid |G|$, then $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ is semisimple by Maschke, and so $\mathbb{F}_p[G]\cong\prod_{i=1}^n M_{n_i}(D_i)$, where $D_i$ are all division algebras over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$;

2) $|G|=p^a$ for some $a\geq 1$, then $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ is local with unique maximal ideal $I$= augmentation ideal. Therefore, $\mathbb{F}_p[G]/I\cong \mathbb{F}_p$;

3) $|G|=kp^a$ for some $a\geq 1$ and $k,p$ coprime. In this case, $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ is a Frobenius algebra with nilpotent radical and so $\mathbb{F}_p[G]/rad\cong\prod_{i=1}^n M_{n_i}(D_i)$, where I believe the $D_i$ are once more division algebras over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and hence again isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Is this all correct? Am I missing anything? Is there anything more we can say about $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$?

Comment: In case 1) it is not necessarily the case that $D_i\simeq\Bbb{F}_p$, it may well be an extension field $\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$ for some $m>1$. It is true that $D_i$ will always be a field though (Wedderburn). So for example when $G$ is abelian $p\nmid|G|$, $\Bbb{F}_p[G]$ will be a direct product of finite fields. The same mistake in 3).

Comment: Ah thank you, that's why I wasn't entirely sure.